# How to use kvm in a Centos 6 docker container via docker machine

Tags: docker, boot2docker, kvm, docker-machine

I'm trying to use kvm in a Centos 6 docker container, via docker machine. My docker machine vm (vmware fusion based) supports nested VMs, but in my docker container I'm seeing:

```
modprobe kvm
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.1.12-boot2docker/modules.dep: No such file or directory
modprobe kvm_intel
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.1.12-boot2docker/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is your reason to use KVM?

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski Not that it matters, but I wish to deploy cloud software, which requires KVM, in a Docker container. I can get KVM running in a Docker container on other platforms (see this https://github.com/ianblenke/docker-kvm), but not Centos 6.

Answer (score 2):

Docker isn't virtual machine. It is a way to package your application.

So I think that running KVM - Kernel Virtual Machine it is not possible inside docker container.

You can read about difference between Docker and other kind of virtualization on page:
https://www.docker.com/what-docker

Comment: Others have run KVM in Docker (one example https://github.com/ianblenke/docker-kvm), but not on CentOS 6 that I can find. That's why I posted here.

Comment: KVM *can* run inside a container, if KVM module is loaded on docker host.

Take a look at https://github.com/BBVA/kvm or https://github.com/rancher/vm

Answer (score 1):

you may need to load the kvm and kvm_intel module on the docker *host* before trying to run the container

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/1138#issuecomment-183199287

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KVM simple container in DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/bbvainnotech/kvm/). [Source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/BBVA/kvm) and has been tested in DockerHosts with Ubuntu 16.04, Centos 7, Centos-Atomic 7.2 and RancherOS.